# Linux Kernel Programming: “Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address [address]”

Tags: c, linux-kernel, nullreferenceexception, kernel, system-calls

For a class assignment, we are writing a custom syscall which pulls certain information about the existing process tree.  The syscall is working fine for the most part and gets the appropriate information.  However, a few processes it, in crashes with the error message, "Unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at virtual address [address]".  What I don't understand is that I'm testing if the pointer is NULL before accessing it, and yet, it still fails.

Example: In the code below, current_process is a valid pointer to a task_struct and k_buf is valid

```
printk("Setting parent process\n");
parent_process = current_process->real_parent;
printk("Parent process set\n");
if (parent_process != NULL) {
printk("Parent process is not null and getting pid\n");
    k_buf[i].parent_pid = parent_process->pid;
} else {
    k_buf[i].parent_pid = 0;
}
printk("Done with parent process\n");
```

When run, the program prints:

```
Setting parent process
Parent process set
Parent process is not null and getting pid
Done with parent process
```

a couple of times, and then

```
Setting parent process
Parent process set
Parent process is not null and getting pid
```

before throwing the error and going into kernel panic.

What am I doing wrong?  Any thoughts?

EDIT:

For the time being, I commented out the above code so I could continue working on the rest of the system call.  When I try to access the pid of a child process (again after a couple of successful attempts), it gives me a "Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address" error.  As far as I understand, I have the correct locks in place for reading this data.  However, is there something else I need to do to check the memory before I access it?

Comment: I have two questions. What are the possible values for real_parent? Is it possible that it is not NULL? Can you print this value and check what it is before the kernel panic? Also, are you sure k_buf[i] dereferences properly? I am not sure, just trying to throw some ideas out there. Edit: I agree with crypto<br />
parent_process->pid is probably null.

Comment: Have you ever seen a case where the `parent_process` was NULL?  I suspect that the NULL pointer is not the obvious pointer access, but more code would be needed to tell.

Comment: In include\linux\sched.h, in the task_struct structure, you'll see that real_parent is a pointer to a task_struct.
If I print the value of parent_process, it will print some integer.  So I guess this means it is not NULL?
However, if I try to print parent_process->pid, it will throw the error and go into kernel panic.
k_buf[i] does dereference properly (tested by trying to assign a int and printing it).

Comment: Yes, I have seen a case where the parent_process is NULL.  For example, the init process (process 1) has a NULL real_parent and will go into the else case.

Comment: Could we see the structure declaration/definition of parent_process please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speculating here but could `parent_process->pid` being `NULL` be the cause of your "kernel panic"? If so, you could check for that too.

Its either that, or some issue with accessing the `i`th element of `k_buf` array ie. `*(k_buf+i)`

Comment: Granted that parent_process appears to be valid (see below comment), I'm leaning towards parent_process->pid being NULL.  However, I test for "if (&parent_process->pid != NULL)" before trying to access it, and I still get the error.

Comment: Huh?  `parent_process->pid` is not a pointer, so how can it be NULL?

Comment: I know it doesn't make sense, but right now, its parent_process->pid that is throwing the error (from my understanding).  I know its not a pointer.  I've been banging my head against a wall for a while now.

Answer (score 1):

You don't seem to be testing `kbuf` of `kbuf[i]` before access.  Also, you can `printk` these pointers, that way you'd catch non-null but obviously invalid addresses (such as `0xbfff0c3a`)

Comment: kbuf and kbuf[i] were valid and had been tested.  Turned out the problem was with current_process.  The way it was being set, it was valid in certain circumstances, invalid in others, but somehow got past the prior NULL checks.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a **system** **call** to list all processes
and got this **error**:

[  260.613411] BUG: unable to handle kernel NULL pointer dereference at 0000000000000040
[  260.613416] PGD 0 P4D 0
[  260.613422] Oops: 0000 [#1] SMP PTI
[  260.613427] CPU: 3 PID: 1793 Comm: a.out Tainted: P           OE     4.19.5 #2

i was checking ,
if( process->parent)
then print its PID,

> Now i think i should try if( process->parent !=NULL)

Answer to Question :
Dear Bro,
You can try,  ppid = task_pid_nr(child_process->parent)
to get pid of parent....!